# Lazy loading don't find the declaration of my component

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

I'm trying to apply lazy loading in my app routing module, but when i exclude the "Dashboard Module" from app.module.ts, my component "DialogConfirmacaoExclusao" is alerted that is not part of any ngModule.

I try:

My app routing module:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: 'dash', loadChildren: 'src/app/components/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'}
];

@NgModule({
  imports:[RouterModule.forChild(appRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule{}
```

In my app.module i import my appRoutingModule e exclude the DashboardModule from the list of imports:

```js
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app.routing.module';
```

My dashboard routing module:

```js
const dashboardRoutes: Routes = [
    {path: 'dash', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
    { path: '', component: BemvindoComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'home', component: BemvindoComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'custofixo', component: CustofixoComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'custoextra', component: CustoextraComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path: 'custovariavel', component: CustovariavelComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path: 'listagemcustofixo', component: CustoMensalFixo, pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path: 'operador', component: OperadorComponent, pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [CadOperadorGuard]},
    { path: 'produtos', component: ProdutoComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path: 'tipoprodutos', component: TipoprodutoComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path: 'meuperfil', component: MeuperfilComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path: 'confestoque', component: ConfEstoqueComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path: 'confprecificacao', component: ConfPrecificacao, pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path: 'monitoramento', component: MonitoramentoComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path: 'listagemcustovariavel', component: CustoMensalVariavel, pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path: 'listagemcustoextra', component: CustoExtraMensal, pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path: 'produtoscalculados', component: ProdutosCalculadosComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
  ]}
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(dashboardRoutes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class DashboardAppRouting {}
```

My dashboard module declare and export the component "DialogConfirmacaoExclusao":

```js
import { DialogConfirmacaoExclusao } from '../dialogexclusao/dialog-exclusao.component';
  exports:[
    DialogConfirmacaoExclusao
]

...

  declarations: [DialogConfirmacaoExclusao]
```

But i receive:

> Uncaught Error: Component DialogConfirmacaoExclusao is not part of any
>   NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.

@Edit:

My app.module.ts:

```js
//Importação de módulos angular
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MyMaterialDesignModule } from '../app.materialdesign.module';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { MDBBootstrapModule } from 'angular-bootstrap-md';
import { NgxMaskModule } from 'ngx-mask';
//Importação de módulos do sistema
import { LoadingModule } from './components/loading/loading.module';
import { DialogEdicaoMovimentacaoModule } from './components/dashboard/dialogedicaomovimentacao/dialog-edicao.module';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app.routing.module';
import { DashboardModule } from './components/dashboard/dashboard.module';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { CustoextraModule } from './components/dashboard/custoextra/custoextra.module';
import { CustovariavelModule } from './components/dashboard/custovariavel/custovariavel.module';
import { OperadorModule } from './components/dashboard/operador/operador.module';
import { TipoProdutoModule } from './components/dashboard/tipoproduto/tipoproduto.module';
import { ProdutoModule } from './components/dashboard/produto/produto.module';
import { LoginModule } from './components/login/login.module';
import { BemVindoModule } from './components/dashboard/bemvindo/bemvindo.module';
import { CustoFixoModule } from './components/dashboard/custofixo/custofixo.module';
import { MeuPerfilModule } from './components/dashboard/meuperfil/meuperfil.module';
import { DialogsModule } from './components/dashboard/dialogedicaolistagemcustos/dialog-edicao.module';
import { ConfEstoqueModule } from './components/dashboard/confestoque/confestoque.module';
import { ConfPrecificacaoModule } from './components/dashboard/confprecificacao/confprecificacao.module';
import { MonitoramentoModule } from './components/dashboard/monitoramento/monitoramento.module';
import { CustoExtraModule } from './components/dashboard/customensalextra/customensalextra.module';
import { SearchPipeModule } from './pipes/searchpipe/searchpipe.module';
import { ProdutosCalculadosModule } from './components/dashboard/produtoscalculados/produtoscalculados.module';
import { DialogEsqueceuSenhaModule } from './components/login/dialogesqueceusenha/dialog-esqueceu-senha.module';
import { CallBackRecuperacaoSenhaModule } from './components/login/callbackrecuperacaosenha/callbackrecuperacaosenha.module';
import { CustoMensalFixoModule } from './components/dashboard/customensalfixo/customensalfixocomponent';
import { CustoMensalVariavelModule } from './components/dashboard/customensalvariavel/customensalvariavel.module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CallBackRecuperacaoSenhaModule,
    CustoMensalFixoModule,
    DialogEdicaoMovimentacaoModule,
    DialogEsqueceuSenhaModule,
    DialogsModule,
    ProdutosCalculadosModule,
    CustoExtraModule,
    SearchPipeModule,
    ConfPrecificacaoModule,
    CustoFixoModule,
    MonitoramentoModule,
    LoadingModule,
    CustoFixoModule,
    TipoProdutoModule,
    ProdutoModule,
    MeuPerfilModule,
    OperadorModule,
    CustovariavelModule,
    CustoextraModule,
    BemVindoModule,
    CustoMensalVariavelModule,
    NgxMaskModule.forRoot(),
    FormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MyMaterialDesignModule,
    MDBBootstrapModule.forRoot(),
    LoginModule,
    DashboardModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ConfEstoqueModule
  ],
  schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [LoginComponent],
})

export class AppModule { }
```

@Edit:

i imported, declared and exported the DialogConfirmacaoExclusao in app.module but now i receive: "dashboard component is not part of any ngmodule..." but don't make sense but if i declare in app module i lose the perform from my lazy loading, right?

Comment: can you please also include here you app.module.ts I think you might be missing something in there

Comment: edited with the app.module

Comment: I think you need to import DialogConfirmacaoExclusao  in you app.module.ts

Comment: i imported, declared and exported the DialogConfirmacaoExclusao in app.module but i still receive: Uncaught Error: Component DialogConfirmacaoExclusao is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.

Comment: @RenaotPLS Can you please describe in detail how your DialogConfirmacaoExclusao and Dashboard component are linked?

Comment: DialogConfirmacaoExclusao is a component of dashboard module. Is imported in dashboard module and declared. But when i use lazy loading, the dialogconfirmacaoExclusao stop find. I receive " is not part of any ngmodule..." if i declare in other module, i receive "Dashboard component is not part of any ngmodule"... both components is declared by Dashboard Module, when i exclude the dashboard module from the importation of my app module, this messages come

Comment: @RenaotPLS Is your DialogConfirmacaoExclusao used any where outside dashboard component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change/swap RouterModule forChild and forRoot functions in AppRoutingModule respectively DashbooardRoutingModule. 
In AppRoutingModule the router should be imported with forRoot. You can have only one `forRoot` in your application and it must be used for your main routing definition:

```
@NgModule({
   imports:[RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
   exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule{}
```

DashboardRoutingModule must use RouterModule with `forChild` function. Every lazy loaded module which contains sub-routing, must be initialized with `forChild`:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(dashboardRoutes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class DashboardAppRouting {}
```

**IMPORTANT:**
Be sure not to include DashboardModule in the AppModule.

Also don't forget to import DashboardRouterModule into DashboardModule, respectively AppRoutingModule into AppModule

Answer (score 2):

You should check the usage of `.forRoot` vs. `.forChild` in the routing modules. As the app module lazily loads the dashboard modules, it should be the other way around (at least that is how I successfully modularized my projects' routing):

```
imports: [RouterModule.forChild(dashboardRoutes)],
```

and

```
imports:[RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
```

[Link to Angular Docs](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules#forroot-and-forchild)

Answer (score 0):

**There could be three posible solutions:**

a) Using relative path loadChildren: './...

b) Using absolute path starting with loadChildren: 'src/app/...

c) tsconfig.app.json --> BaseUrl: "./"

Actually, the problem comes from typescript config.

Before NG 6, the scaffold generated by CLI set the BaseUrl in tsconfig.app.json which is located inside /src. Currently, it is set by tsconfig.json located outside /src, but continues pointing to ./. Because of this, loadChildren path to module should be relative or include src folder.